# How could the effectiveness of guided weapons be reduced against a non-paranormal giant monster?

Tags: military, creature-design

How could the effectiveness of radar, heat seeking, or laser guided weapons be reduced during a battle between a monster the size of a 7 story building and the military of a small country.

The monster is purely biological, and has no paranormal powers or abilities, and would die quickly if hit with modern anti tank weapons because its armor is "realistic" and couldn't stand up to something designed to kill a tank for long.

Something that would force the military to use unguided weapons, wire guided anti-tank weapons with a human operator (The TOW, for example).

Maybe an environmental factor that could artificially constrain battles to being within visual range?

Comment: Don't have to reduce it. Military self-guided weapons are not designed to seek animals. (On the contrary, they are designed to actively *cancel* signals which look like biologicals.) On the other hand, "visual range" for modern-ish anti-tank self-propelled artillery is measured in kilometers. The monster has no chance.

Comment: How about setting up a demonstration against the government of that small country, to rescue these poor non-paranormal giant animals from modern warfare practices :p

Comment: "The monster is purely biological, and has no paranormal powers or abilities" The square-cube law would like to have a word. AFAIK there are basically no ways to make "realistic" walking, biological Kaiju without some sort of supermaterial or supernatural meddling involved due to the physical stresses that arise.

Comment: @Dragongeek 7 story building is large dino territory. Brachiosaurus was about 15m, and that wasn't the largest.

Comment: @Corvus 7 stories is about 30 meters, and while there were dinos some that approached the head-to-tail of 25m, a large portion of that number comes from a long skinny neck and tail. Personally, I don't think that really counts when describing a kaiju.

Answer (score 9):

A lot of systems are looking for an infrared signature, or perhaps doing some image processing to identify the manmade object in a natural background. Since your monster is biological it has low thermal contrast and since it doesn't look like tanks or other objects that the automated systems were designed for, they need to be manually pointed or controlled.

Some systems use laser designators where an operator shines a laser on an object and the guided bomb is designed to hit the spot being illuminated.

For your creature, its skin/fur/coating is black because it evolved for stealth, and the structure of the skin/fur/coating traps the light very efficiently so the laser designators don't work.

For radar, you could also go the absorption route to minimize signal return, or you could have angular surfaces that reflect the energy up and away from the platform trying to shine its radar on the creature.  Or if it is in a urban environment there could be a lot of radar clutter.

Environmental factors include smoke and fog, both can limit the effectiveness of modern weapon systems.

Comment: Animals on the ground are pretty much invisible to radar -- the difference in radar reflection between the animal and the ground is much too low. *Lidar*, on the other hand...

Comment: As high frequency chips become cheaper there is more interest in radar for doing things like distinguishing  humans from animals for security systems and for medical uses such as obtaining physiological parameters. A lot of time there is some sensor fusion where the radar is combined with other sensors like camera., but point taken for animals on the ground. Although this animal is 7 stories tall and might stick out some. For insects and birds weather radars data is apparently useful for biologists studying migration patterns.

Comment: "its skin/fur/coating is black ... so the laser designators don't work" - are you saying that people can simply paint their tanks black to avoid laser-guided bombs"?

Comment: In principle yes. You can have light trapping coatings and greatly reduce the reflection. If the reflection and scatter is greatly reduced less light for the imaging system to acquire the target. Some of the newer light trappings technologies are very good I think the record is from MIT and it is 99.995 absorptive.  There are also some pretty efficient biological structures on deep sea fish skins and some birds that can absorb 99.5 percent of the light.

Comment: @Alexander, note that a black tank is highly visible to a human firing a wire-guided, radar-guided, or unguided antitank missile, so don't expect to find black tanks on the battlefield any time soon.

Comment: @Mark in that case not tanks, but equipment farther from the front lines, like artillery and anti-aircraft batteries - they are also highly vulnerable to laser guided munitions, and yet I don't see any attempts to paint them pitch black.

Comment: @Alexander, that's the visibility issue again: they're both vulnerable to things other than laser-guided bombs, so "don't be seen" is a better defense than "don't be targetable by this one particular weapon".

Comment: For vehicles behind the line of sight from the front lines, laser-guided munitions is a #1 threat (from an opponent that possess them). If we can thwart 50% or more of such attacks, this should well outweigh the risk of higher visibility.

Comment: @Alexander The light trapping materials are usually demonstrated on small areas, and probably have adhesion problems and other practical issues. Cost is high. The heating up from sunlight  being trapped. Could be an issue. That said, there is substantial interest in developing coatings and fabrics and other tech that changes the IR signature by changing the emissivity. That’s a little different than light trapping but will probably be adopted in various ways too.  I suspect with all the drones being used for targeting there is going to be increased interest in better camouflage too.

Answer (score 6):

**Counterfire.**

The monster has acute senses.  And even though it is big, it is fast.  It can hear a tank missile taking off.  It throws something to meet the missile - maybe a scoop of earth, or flying spikes, or projectile vomit or whatever works.

To hit the monster with something like a missile you need to get very close so it does not have time to react.  Many of the antitank munitions do not arm themselves if they have not flown a certain distance, and then they bounce off.

Perhaps your humans set up a remote controlled missile launch station in the monster's predicted path.   They neglect to set it up downwind from the monster.  The monster has acute senses.

---

**Advanced armaments used up.**

[Has America almost depleted its supply of essential weapons for Ukraine?](https://www.washingtontimes.com/news/2022/may/3/has-america-almost-depleted-its-supply-of-essentia/)

> Albert Einstein famously said, “I know not with what weapons World War
> III will be fought, but World War IV will be fought with sticks and
> stones”...

In the world where this monster shows up, there has been a war.  Or maybe the war is still going on.  Sophisticated antitank weapons were largely used up early in the war; few remain.  The industry to make more is also either gone or is devoting efforts to munitions that are cheaper and quicker to make.

Comment: Just fire 10 missiles at it and game over, no way it can get all of it. On top of that many missiles go faster than the speed of sound so a reaction may even be impossible.

Comment: @Behacad - missiles fly faster than the speed of sound but they dont start off that fast and the sound of their launch and acceleratiion will reach the monster before they do.  As regards 10 missiles I had a different idea on that front and I will put it as an addendum to this one.

Comment: If you launch from far enough away, the sound of the launch definitely won't get to the monster before a supersonic missile does.

Answer (score 5):

**Aluminum!**

Okay, let me explain. All three of these guiding techniques you mention use a scanning method to track their target. And all of them can be countered with (relatively) simple approaches.

**Laser Guidance:** This uses a method called laser painting where you fire a laser at the target and then the missile (or what have you) tracks the target based on how the laser scatters off of it. If the target does *not* scatter the laser and instead absorbs it, then the laser guidance is mostly useless. Laser scattering materials include black aluminum.

**Heat-seeking:** Heat seekers, despite their name, do not actually seek out heat. They seek out infrared light, which is generated by heat. This distinction is important, because it is possible to block infrared light with a conductive metal, like say, aluminum.

**Radar**: Radar is surprisingly effective to use to guide weapons, but there is a caveat - radar sucks at distinguishing objects. In an isolated environment, (i.e. open sky) then yes, it is useful. If you're fighting a kaiju in a building-dotted landscape ... not so much.
Also, radar can be tricked by scattering ions and ion deflectors all over the atmosphere. like say, aluminum. So the monster can belch clouds of aluminum all around it and the radar will be tricked.

Tl;dr - aluminum OP against detection methods, plz nerf.

Comment: No self-respecting military heat-seeking missile will ever even bother considering barely luke-warm objects such as animals. They are looking for *hot* objects, such as the exhaust of a tank or aircraft engine.

Comment: @AlexP Fair enough, though kaiju have a tendency to emit fire breath or be powered by nuclear reactors. I know this is supposed to be 'purely biological', but biological fire breath has come up on this site numerous times.

Comment: Yes, they do, but that would be in direct contradiction with this answer. it's hard to make a stealthy flamethrower.

Comment: It is when the flamethrower isn't in use.

Answer (score 4):

### Speedy flock of monsters

I live in a small country. Ok, let's suppose this thing is 7 stories high and it eats humans.

And it is not the only one. He brought his herd along, which was 300 individuals at first. Some 15-20 meters each, a herd of predators the size of a brontosaurus approaches my small country.

**Fast and unpredictable**

The Germans tried to use cruise missiles against them last night and failed. These beasts are agile, they are not moving in straight lines, like military vehicles and ships do. The herd behaves like a flock of birds, roaming around for food. These monsters need about 1600kg meat per day.

The herd now moves toward us. They appeared to have crossed the Polish border yesterday evening and then they did Northern Germany overnight. Alarms were set off, NATO fighter jets were deployed, some monsters were killed but it required low altitude flight and agility to keep up with them. No actual practice was ever done by the military, chasing monsters 7 stories high, running at about 200km/h.

**Danger of collateral damage in a small country**

In Poland and Germany, the damage done by the military far exceeded the damage resulting from the flock's presence.

In our overpopulated small country, the collateral damage problem will be worse and that prevented a quick response with our guided artillery. About 280 monsters reached our small country at noon today. The herd passed the German border near Klazienaveen and the population was not prepared for that. These monsters don't walk straight, they roam around and steal cattle, ravage houses, eat people. Multiple Dutch villages got rampaged by them, 60 folks died and about 200 people were wounded. Some are still missing. Their break for dinner was 2 hours later where I live. I managed to escape one.

When drinking or eating, they would be sitting duck for heavy weaponry. But.. how to attack these monsters when they are having dinner where the meat is, that is in populated areas?

**They passed**

Some experts in herd behaviour were consulted by our government and a military strategy was devised. But late in the afternoon today, the herd had already passed the Belgium border in the south. The government decided to cancel the whole plan and let Belgium solve their issue.

Comment: "but it required low altitude flight and agility to keep up with them."

So easy kills for helicopters and close air support aircraft?

Comment: Ahh the “Let them eat Belgians” solution

Answer (score 3):

### The creature lives underwater

Not only would this sidestep the square-cube size limitations that land-bound creatures have and enable the hypothetical construction of truly massive yet still biological creatures, it would also render most conventional weapons useless as they can't attack underwater.

No modern AT or AA weaponry is effective against targets under basically any depth of water and this includes everything from missiles to mortars to artillery. So long as the creature can withstand the shockwaves that heavy explosives can cause and dive more than 10 meters or so, it is basically insulated from everything a modern army can throw at it excepting:

- Truly big explosives up to and including nuclear ones (the creature would likely need to dive more than 10 meters to avoid these but still easily possible)
- Specifically designed underwater weaponry like mines, depth charges, or torpedoes.

Interestingly, such a creature could possibly even "defeat" the small country in the sense that it acts as a complete naval blockade, sinking all ships that approach its shores. Provided it alpha-strikes the likely small force of submarines and realizes that torpedoes are things it needs to dodge, there is very little that could reach a creature 100 meters down. It just occasionally reaches it's tentacles or whatever up to sink ships, and otherwise stays in the untouchable depths.

Comment: Torpedoes do exist.

Comment: @AlexP I addressed this in my answer at multiple locations: "Specifically designed underwater weaponry like mines, depth charges, or torpedoes." Also, torpedoes are slow enough to be dodge-able as while hypercavitating torpedoes have been developed, it is unlikely that a non-superpower would have any.